# Transmitting as a Beacon with two-letter language code

Tags: ibeacon-android

I use Android Beacon Library to transmit as iBeacon, then another android mobile phone, which language code is "en", can show the Nearby Notification. But when the language code of the mobile phone is not "en", I cannot see the Nearby Notification.
So can Android Beacon Library set two-letter language code, like google beacon platform dashboard?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZwbL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Understand that setting a language code in the Google Beacon Platfrorm dashboard simply sets a *filter* so that the nearby message is only displayed on an Android phone if two conditions are met:

1. The beacon is detected.
2. The phone has the language set to a value that matches a filter in the dashniard for the message

The first condition is met by the beacon transmitter (Android Beacon Library or otherwise)

The second condition is controlled by the Google Beacon Platform, not the beacon. It refuses to display messages where the phone's language does not match the message's language.   If you want the message to show for phones with other language settings, simply add other language codes for the message in the Google Beacon Platform.

Beacons do not communicate with the Google Beacon Platform, so you have to set the language settings for your messages directly.